# Для знатоков SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Всем добрый день! Интересует вопрос как с помощью SQL запроса можно сделать многомерный массив.

Итак. Есть 3 таблицы например

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `films` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_janr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

--

### -- Дамп данных таблицы `films`

```
INSERT INTO `films` (`id`, `name`, `id_janr`) VALUES
(1, 'Кошмар на улице вязов 1', 1),
(2, 'Кошмар на улице вязов 2', 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `janr` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

--

### -- Дамп данных таблицы `janr`

```
INSERT INTO `janr` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Ужасы');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rejeser` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_janr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

--

### -- Дамп данных таблицы `rejeser`

```
INSERT INTO `rejeser` (`id`, `firstname`, `id_janr`) VALUES
(1, 'Режисер 1', 1),
(2, 'Режисер 2', 1),
(3, 'Режисер 3', 1),
(4, 'Режисер 4', 1);
```

Нужно сделать запрос который бы позволял при выборке из таблицы жанр в результат получать вот такой массив.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ужасы
            [films] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Кошммар на улице вязов
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Кошммар на улице вязов 2
                        )

                )

            [rejeser] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [firstname] => Режисер 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [firstname] => Режисер 2
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [firstname] => Режисер 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Я вижу это как то так

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  title, 
  films as (SELECT * FROM films WHERE id_janr = id), 
  rejeser as (SELECT * FROM rejeser WHERE id_janr = id) 
FROM janr
```

но естественно этот вариант не работает. Какие еще могут быть варианты рабочие для получения нужного результата ?

Comment: SQL может возвращать только двумерную таблицу и никак иначе. Самым простым решением будет последовательно получить нужные данные из каждой из таблиц и сложить результирующие массивы в один большой. буквально `array('title' => $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM), 'rejeser' => $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM), ... )`

Comment: а зачем это нужно?

Comment: @Dmitriy Предполагается перебор огромного кол-ва данных в цикле. И делать циклы в цикле плохая логика по этому думаю как можно за одну итерацию цикла сделать все что необходимо.

Comment: @Mike как это будет выглядеть в готовом виде ?

Comment: вот прямо как я написал. только $query1 и т.п. перед сборкой этого массива подготовьте, т.е. сделайте prepare и execute

Comment: хотя нет, я подумал вы информацию по одному фильму хотите. У вас же все сложнее. Вы вообще не соберете это, потому что у вас нет в БД данных о принадлежности фильмов жанрам. Только почему то режиссеры как то относятся к жанрам и почему то только 1 жанр на одного режиссера.

Comment: @Mike и фильмы и режисеры имеют маркер на жанр. это поле id_janr

Comment: Если бы информация была, я бы предложил сначала загрузить список фильмов в разрезе жанров, получить таким образом начальные измерения массива. Потом целиком считать всю таблицу режиссеров с join на таблицу вхождения режисеров в фильм (у вас же есть такая таблица ?)  и прямо по id фильмов читая эти данные разложить в нужные точки массива. И так же с остальными таблицами

Comment: Очень редко какие режиссеры снимают строго в одном жанре> Так что жанр режиссера скорее всего бесполезен. Так же редко какие фильмы относятся строго к одному жанру. Обычно фильм принадлежит сразу нескольким жанрам. Но конечно если вы хотите строго одиночное сопоставление - то модель корректная

Comment: @Mike дело в том что таблицы будут просто огромные и делать 3 запроса по каждой таблице отдельно с выборкой всех данных что бы в последствии сгруппировать их в массив это слишком емкая процедура. Я хочу уйти от такой модели. А фильмы жанры и режисеры просто упрощенная форма как пример для обучения

Comment: А у вас итоговый массив содержит данные этих самых таблиц целиком. Тут нет каких либо сгруппированных данных. И почему "_что бы в последствии сгруппировать_" ? Группировка данных производится да, вручную, но прямо в момент чтения из курсора БД, без предварительной выборки в отдельный массив. Так что при нормально настроенных драйверах БД в php потребление памяти будет точно под результирующий массив плюс небольшой буфер на чтение

Comment: @Mike данные же могут быть различные это же примерные данные. Ответьте лучше возможно ли с помощью одного SQL запроса получить нужный мне вариант массива или такое невозможно в принципе. Как сделать эту задачу другими способами я знаю.

Comment: На это я ответил в первом комментарии: реляционные базы данных могут возвращать данные только в двумерном виде и никак иначе.

Comment: @Mike тогда вопрос снимается. Благодарю